# Hiding .js files when having .ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I just downaloade TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015. I am writing .ts file and it created .js file in the same level in solution. Does anyone know how to hide the .js file or have it 'inside' .ts so I could just expand .ts tree and see .js?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2326

Comment: You don't have to create your `.js` file by yourself. If you use the Visual Studio TS Compiler the `js` files will be generated automatically for you. These generated files by default are not visible in the solution explorer, unless you toggle the button to show all files.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your project to create .js files in a specific folder.

In VS 2015, you can set the build directory from "Redirect Javascript output to directory" in the typescript build section of your project properties page.

[image]

If you use a tsconfig.json the project property pages will all be grayed out but you can specify the directory in the tsconfig.json file:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
```